# How to put an option from <select> into a variable to populate a table in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm an high school Italian student, and today my professor assigned me a simple homework:

I have to create a PHP page with a basic form that allows me to introduce a new "student" into a table in MySQL, "name", "surname" and "class".

That's the PHP page:

```php
<html>
<head>
<title> School </title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$name="";
$surname="";
$conn=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","");
if(!$conn){ echo 'No connection.'; die;}
if(!mysqli_select_db($conn,"School")) { echo 'Err'; die;}
$result=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from classes");

if(!isset($_REQUEST["submit"])){

    echo '<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" size="26"> Name <br><br>
    <input type="text" name="surname" size="26"> Surname <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">';
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)!=0){
        echo '<select name="combobox" id="combobox">
        <option value="" selected="selected"> Classes list </option>';
        while($combobox=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $classes=$combobox["classes"];
            echo '<option value="'.$combobox["classes"].'">'.$combobox["classes"].'</option>';
        }
        echo '</select><br><br>';
    }
    echo '</form>';

}
else{
    $name=$_REQUEST["name"];
    $surname=$_REQUEST["surname"];
    //$query='insert into Students(name,surname,classes) values("'.$name.'","'.$surname.'","'.$classes.'");';
    //if(!mysqli_query($conn,$query)) { echo 'Err'; die; }
    echo 'Success! <br> Name: '.$name.' <br> Surname: '.$surname.'<br> Class: '.$classes.'<br>';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I have already created the database with all the tables I need. Now, the thing is, how do I put the "option" that I choose from the `<select>` into a variable so I can use it for the `insert into`? Everything I found was just "filling a combobox from mysql".

Comment: Always post your code here. Link may be expired in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get value of select give it name and after get it by it's name with `$_GET['name']` or `$_POST['name']` if you choose `method="post"`, you will get the selected option value.

html:

```
 <form method="get" action="/script.php">
 <select name="name"><option>1</option></select>
 <input type="submit" value="send">
 </form>
```

php:

```
 $value=$_GET['name']; 
 echo $value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Always give your form elements a `name`, this is how it gets sent to the backend. With `<select>`, the value of the selected element will be sent to your code via the name you gave it. Once you do this, you can add a variable for it at the end of your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO MyDB (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

This is what you should follow.